# Powershell remoting out-file to share credentials

Tags: powershell, share, powershell-remoting

I am trying to create a script that recolects information using remote powershel and saves the info to a share. I am having trouble to write the output to the file share because y am getting access denied error even though that I have granted full control to everyone and anonymous logon over de share.

[image]

```
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName coboap31 -ScriptBlock {hostname| Out-File -FilePath  $("\\coboap31\Info\" + $env:COMPUTERNAME +".log") -Append}
```

Any ideas about how I must authenticate to the share?

Comment: You shouldn't present essential information as a picture, better copy and paste the text from the console as text. If you prepend the error message with a `>` it's shown in a yellow box.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you get a error of not authenticating against the network target.

This is by design.

You can go several ways to fix this issue. See [this link for examples](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/08/30/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely/), to see what matches best for your requirements.

Comment: Link only answers to external sources aren't real answers, you should elaborate on the issue in case the link gets unreachable in the future.